# Directing user sessions to specific hardware stacks

Tags: proxy, load-balancing

Customer has chosen a COTS product that supports 100 concurrent users max but they have 500 concurrent users. The users work on their own data silos so there is no cross sharing. A proposal could be to build 5 stacks each having capacity for 100 users. This could mean a solution would require assurance individual network users are first assigned then fixed to a specific back-end stack each time they log in.

All authenticated users come in through a VMWare VDI. What type of server/service could be put up front the connections and allow rules to match a specific user (authenticated through active directory via a VMWare VDI) to a specific back-end stack. A load balancer or proxy has been suggested. Recommendations as to the approach would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If you don't have anything yet one "solution" can of course be as  simple as creating and naming the required number of unique stacks and then once you provision particular users in a specific stack you  instruct them to log in to that particular stack with the unique stack name  `stack[1-5].app.example.com`...

Comment: The border between a software recommendation and the solution of a problem is not really exact, I think the question is yet on the on-topic side.